# ADF Mapping Dataflows performance very low as compared to Databricks when performing same set of transformations

Tags: performance, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am doing same set of transformation using ADF Mapping Dataflows and Databricks. Dataflows takes around 2 hours whereas Databricks is taking only 8-10 mins for the same volume of data. As i understand they both use Apache Spark in the back-end, can someone please help me understand this behavior.

Dataflow Script:

```
{
"name": "df_Test",
"properties": {
    "type": "MappingDataFlow",
    "typeProperties": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_ST_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "SalesTransactionUS"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_SC_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "ShipToCustomer"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_PG_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "PlantGlobal"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_M_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "Materials"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_C_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "Country"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_A_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "Airport"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_SL_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "ShipToLocation"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_LD_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "LookupDivision"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_LCT_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "LookupCurrencyType"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_PCH_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "ProfitCenterHierarchy"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_DCal_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "DateCalculations"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_CUOM_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "CurrencyUOM"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_UUOM_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "UnitUOM"
            },
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_LSDTS_SourceRefined",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "LookupSalesDocument"
            }
        ],
        "sinks": [
            {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "ds_STS_SinkProduce",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "name": "sinkToProduce"
            }
        ],
        "transformations": [
            {
                "name": "ProfitCentreJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "ShipToCustomerJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "PlantGlobalJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "MaterialsJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "AirportJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "ShipToLocationJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "LookupDivisionJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "LookupCurrencyTypeJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "CountryJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "DateCalculationJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "CurrencyUOMJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "UnitUOMJoin"
            },
            {
                "name": "SelectColumns"
            },
            {
                "name": "LookupSalesDocumentJoin"
            }
        ],
        "script": "source(output(\n\t\tDateCalcKey as integer,\n\t\tCurrencyUOMKey as integer,\n\t\tUOMkey as integer,\n\t\tUnitUOMKey as integer,\n\t\tSalesTransactionKey as long,\n\t\tTransactionUniqueIdentifier as string,\n\t\tSourceCode as string,\n\t\tAccountingDocumentNumber as string,\n\t\tCompanyCode as string,\n\t\tTransactionType as string,\n\t\tSalesDocumentItem as integer,\n\t\tReferenceDocument as string,\n\t\tOrderNumber as string,\n\t\tPurchaseOrderNumber as string,\n\t\tReferenceItem as integer,\n\t\tSalesContractNumber as string,\n\t\tSalesContractType as string,\n\t\tSalesReferenceDocument as string,\n\t\tSenderCostCenter as string,\n\t\tCurrencyTypeKey as integer,\n\t\tProfitCenterKey as integer,\n\t\tDivisionKey as integer,\n\t\tPlantKey as integer,\n\t\tMaterialKey as integer,\n\t\tShipToKey as integer,\n\t\tSoldToConsolidatedCustomerNumber as string,\n\t\tSoldToKey as integer,\n\t\tPostingDayId as integer,\n\t\tSalesDocumentKey as integer,\n\t\tCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tRegionCode as string,\n\t\tAirportKey as integer,\n\t\tLocationKey as integer,\n\t\tShipToAirportCode as string,\n\t\tKPIElementCode as string,\n\t\tShipToCustomerPlantKey as integer,\n\t\tMeasures as decimal(19,3),\n\t\tSalesTransactionPostingMonthId as integer\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: false,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> SalesTransactionUS\nsource(output(\n\t\tShipToKey as integer,\n\t\tShipToNumber as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesOrganization as string,\n\t\tShipToDistributionChannel as string,\n\t\tShipToDivision as string,\n\t\tAlternateSalesGroupIndicator as integer,\n\t\tSourceCode as string,\n\t\tShipToDisplayName as string,\n\t\tShipToName as string,\n\t\tShipToAddress as string,\n\t\tShipToCity as string,\n\t\tShipToState as string,\n\t\tShipToPostalCode as string,\n\t\tShipToCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tShipToLevel1 as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel1Description as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel1Cai as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel2 as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel2Description as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel2Cai as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel3 as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel3Description as string,\n\t\tShipToLevel3Cai as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesOffice as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesOfficeDescription as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesOfficeCai as string,\n\t\tShipToDistrict as string,\n\t\tShipToDistrictDescription as string,\n\t\tShipToDistrictCai as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesGroup as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesGroupDescription as string,\n\t\tShipToSalesGroupCai as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustry as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustryName as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySegment as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySegmentName as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySegmentLynxCode as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySegmentLynxName as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySegmentGroup as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySubSegment as string,\n\t\tShipToIndustrySubSegmentName as string,\n\t\tShipToIataCode as string,\n\t\tShipToAirportCode as string,\n\t\tShipToAirportName as string,\n\t\tShipToAirportCodeFlag as string,\n\t\tShipToDifferentialReferenceCode as string,\n\t\tSoldtoKey as integer,\n\t\tSoldToNumber as string,\n\t\tSoldToName as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesOrganization as string,\n\t\tSoldToDistributionChannel as string,\n\t\tSoldToDivision as string,\n\t\tSoldToAddress as string,\n\t\tSoldToCity as string,\n\t\tSoldToState as string,\n\t\tSoldToPostalCode as string,\n\t\tSoldToCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tSoldToLevel1 as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel1Description as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel1Cai as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel2 as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel2Description as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel2Cai as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel3 as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel3Description as string,\n\t\tSoldToLevel3Cai as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesOffice as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesOfficeDescription as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesOfficeCai as string,\n\t\tSoldToDistrict as string,\n\t\tSoldToDistrictDescription as string,\n\t\tSoldToDistrictCai as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesGroup as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesGroupDescription as string,\n\t\tSoldToSalesGroupCai as string,\n\t\tSoldToIataCode as string,\n\t\tSoldToAirportCode as string,\n\t\tSoldToDifferentialReferenceCode as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustry as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustryName as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySegment as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySegmentName as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySegmentLynxCode as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySegmentLynxName as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySegmentGroup as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySubSegment as string,\n\t\tSoldToIndustrySubSegmentName as string,\n\t\tSoldToConsolidatedCustomerNumber as string,\n\t\tSoldToConsolidatedCustomerName as string,\n\t\tSubSourceCode as string,\n\t\tABCClassification as string,\n\t\tSoldToMosCustomerNumber as string,\n\t\tSoldToMosCustomerName as string,\n\t\tSoldToWithSalesGroup as string,\n\t\tShipToWithSalesGroup as string,\n\t\tShipToDeliveringPlant as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> ShipToCustomer\nsource(output(\n\t\tPlantKey as integer,\n\t\tPlant as string,\n\t\tValuationArea as string,\n\t\tCustomerNumber as string,\n\t\tPurchaseOrganization as string,\n\t\tSalesOrganization as string,\n\t\tDistributionChannel as string,\n\t\tSalesDivision as string,\n\t\tTaxIndicator as string,\n\t\tPlantTitle as string,\n\t\tName1 as string,\n\t\tName3 as string,\n\t\tName4 as string,\n\t\tCity as string,\n\t\tCountyCode as string,\n\t\tCounty as string,\n\t\tPostalCode as string,\n\t\tAddress as string,\n\t\tCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tCountryName as string,\n\t\tRegionName as string,\n\t\tState as string,\n\t\tAddressGroup as string,\n\t\tAddressSource as string,\n\t\tTaxJurisdictionCode as string,\n\t\tIATACode as string,\n\t\tOperationsArea as string,\n\t\tDeleteIndicator as string,\n\t\tRefineryArea as string,\n\t\tSourceCode as string,\n\t\tSubSourceCode as string,\n\t\tActiveIndicator as boolean,\n\t\tSapType as string,\n\t\tTerminalFlag as string,\n\t\tPlantType as string,\n\t\tOldCode as string,\n\t\tTerminalCenter as string,\n\t\tTransportationCenter as string,\n\t\tSupplyAreaCode as string,\n\t\tSupplyAreaName as string,\n\t\tDistributiveArea as string,\n\t\tPlantSubType as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> PlantGlobal\nsource(output(\n\t\tMaterialKey as integer,\n\t\tMaterialNumber as string,\n\t\tSourceCode as string,\n\t\tMaterialDescription as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel5 as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel5Description as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel4 as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel4Description as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel3 as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel3Description as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel2 as string,\n\t\tHierarchyLevel2Description as string,\n\t\tMaterialGroup as string,\n\t\tBrandCode as string,\n\t\tExternalMaterialGroup as string,\n\t\tSubSourceCode as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> Materials\nsource(output(\n\t\tCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tCountryCode as string,\n\t\tCountryName as string,\n\t\tDefaultCurrencyCode as string,\n\t\tDefaultVolumeUom as string,\n\t\tDefaultUomRate as string,\n\t\tDefaultSalesOrganization as string,\n\t\tCurrencyFormat as string,\n\t\tCurrencyFormatDecimalPlaces as string,\n\t\tRegionCode as string,\n\t\tRegionName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> Country\nsource(output(\n\t\tAirportKey as integer,\n\t\tAirportCode as string,\n\t\tAirportName as string,\n\t\tAirportCodeName as string,\n\t\tAirportDescription as string,\n\t\tActiveIndicator as boolean,\n\t\tSortOrder as integer\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> Airport\nsource(output(\n\t\tLocationKey as integer,\n\t\tLocationId as string,\n\t\tSourceCode as string,\n\t\tStartDate as timestamp,\n\t\tEndDate as timestamp,\n\t\tName as string,\n\t\tAddress as string,\n\t\tCity as string,\n\t\tState as string,\n\t\tCountryKey as integer,\n\t\tCountryName as string,\n\t\tLocationType as string,\n\t\tLocationTypeName as string,\n\t\tLocationStatusKey as integer,\n\t\tLocationStatusName as string,\n\t\tPostalCode as string,\n\t\tProfitCenterKey as integer,\n\t\tCostCenter as string,\n\t\tPlantKey as integer,\n\t\tCountryCode as string,\n\t\tShipToKey as integer,\n\t\tSubsourcecode as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> ShipToLocation\nsource(output(\n\t\tDivisionKey as integer,\n\t\tDivision as string,\n\t\tDivisionName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> LookupDivision\nsource(output(\n\t\tCurrencyTypeKey as integer,\n\t\tCurrencyType as string,\n\t\tCurrencyTypeName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> LookupCurrencyType\nsource(output(\n\t\tProfitCenterKey as integer,\n\t\tProfitCenter as string,\n\t\tProfitCenterName as string,\n\t\tBusinessAreaName as string,\n\t\tCountryCode as string,\n\t\tCountryName as string,\n\t\tRegionCode as string,\n\t\tRegionName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> ProfitCenterHierarchy\nsource(output(\n\t\tDateCalcKey as integer,\n\t\tDateCalcDesc as string,\n\t\tSortOrder as integer\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: false,\n\tvalidateSchema: true,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> DateCalculations\nsource(output(\n\t\tCurrencyUOMKey as integer,\n\t\tCurrencyUOMName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> CurrencyUOM\nsource(output(\n\t\tUnitUOMKey as integer,\n\t\tUnitUOMName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> UnitUOM\nsource(output(\n\t\tSalesDocumentKey as integer,\n\t\tSalesDocumentType as string,\n\t\tSalesDocumentName as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet') ~> LookupSalesDocument\nSalesTransactionUS, ProfitCenterHierarchy join(SalesTransactionUS@ProfitCenterKey == ProfitCenterHierarchy@ProfitCenterKey,\n\tjoinType:'left',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> ProfitCentreJoin\nCountryJoin, ShipToCustomer join(SalesTransactionUS@ShipToKey == ShipToCustomer@ShipToKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> ShipToCustomerJoin\nShipToCustomerJoin, PlantGlobal join(SalesTransactionUS@PlantKey == PlantGlobal@PlantKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> PlantGlobalJoin\nPlantGlobalJoin, Materials join(SalesTransactionUS@MaterialKey == Materials@MaterialKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> MaterialsJoin\nMaterialsJoin, Airport join(SalesTransactionUS@AirportKey == Airport@AirportKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> AirportJoin\nAirportJoin, ShipToLocation join(SalesTransactionUS@LocationKey == ShipToLocation@LocationKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> ShipToLocationJoin\nShipToLocationJoin, LookupDivision join(SalesTransactionUS@DivisionKey == LookupDivision@DivisionKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> LookupDivisionJoin\nLookupDivisionJoin, LookupCurrencyType join(SalesTransactionUS@CurrencyTypeKey == LookupCurrencyType@CurrencyTypeKey,\n\tjoinType:'left',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> LookupCurrencyTypeJoin\nProfitCentreJoin, Country join(SalesTransactionUS@CountryKey == Country@CountryKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> CountryJoin\nLookupCurrencyTypeJoin, DateCalculations join(SalesTransactionUS@DateCalcKey == DateCalculations@DateCalcKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> DateCalculationJoin\nDateCalculationJoin, CurrencyUOM join(SalesTransactionUS@CurrencyUOMKey == CurrencyUOM@CurrencyUOMKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> CurrencyUOMJoin\nCurrencyUOMJoin, UnitUOM join(SalesTransactionUS@UnitUOMKey == UnitUOM@UnitUOMKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> UnitUOMJoin\nLookupSalesDocumentJoin select(mapColumn(\n\t\tDateCalcDesc,\n\t\tSortOrder = DateCalculations@SortOrder,\n\t\tCurrencyUOMName,\n\t\tUOMkey,\n\t\tUnitUOMName,\n\t\tSalesTransactionKey,\n\t\tTransactionUniqueIdentifier,\n\t\tSourceCode = SalesTransactionUS@SourceCode,\n\t\tAccountingDocumentNumber,\n\t\tCompanyCode,\n\t\tTransactionType,\n\t\tSalesDocumentItem,\n\t\tReferenceDocument,\n\t\tOrderNumber,\n\t\tPurchaseOrderNumber,\n\t\tReferenceItem,\n\t\tSalesContractNumber,\n\t\tSalesContractType,\n\t\tSalesReferenceDocument,\n\t\tSenderCostCenter,\n\t\tCurrencyType,\n\t\tCurrencyTypeName,\n\t\tProfitCenter,\n\t\tProfitCenterName,\n\t\tBusinessAreaName,\n\t\tProfitCentreCountryCode = ProfitCenterHierarchy@CountryCode,\n\t\tProfitCentreCountryName = ProfitCenterHierarchy@CountryName,\n\t\tProfitCentreRegionCode = ProfitCenterHierarchy@RegionCode,\n\t\tProfitCentreRegionName = ProfitCenterHierarchy@RegionName,\n\t\tDivision,\n\t\tDivisionName,\n\t\tPlant,\n\t\tMaterialNumber,\n\t\tShipToNumber,\n\t\tSoldToConsolidatedCustomerNumber = SalesTransactionUS@SoldToConsolidatedCustomerNumber,\n\t\tSoldToNumber,\n\t\tPostingDayId,\n\t\tPostingMonthId = SalesTransactionPostingMonthId,\n\t\tSalesDocumentName,\n\t\tRegionCode = SalesTransactionUS@RegionCode,\n\t\tCountryCode = Country@CountryCode,\n\t\tCountryName = Country@CountryName,\n\t\tDefaultCurrencyCode,\n\t\tDefaultVolumeUom,\n\t\tDefaultUomRate,\n\t\tDefaultSalesOrganization,\n\t\tCurrencyFormat,\n\t\tCurrencyFormatDecimalPlaces,\n\t\tRegionName = Country@RegionName,\n\t\tAirportCode,\n\t\tLocationId,\n\t\tShipToAirportCode = SalesTransactionUS@ShipToAirportCode,\n\t\tKPIElementCode,\n\t\tShipToCustomerPlantKey,\n\t\tMeasures\n\t),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> SelectColumns\nUnitUOMJoin, LookupSalesDocument join(SalesTransactionUS@SalesDocumentKey == LookupSalesDocument@SalesDocumentKey,\n\tjoinType:'inner',\n\tbroadcast: 'auto')~> LookupSalesDocumentJoin\nSelectColumns sink(input(\n\t\tAirportKey as integer,\n\t\tAirportCode as string,\n\t\tAirportName as string,\n\t\tAirportCodeName as string,\n\t\tAirportDescription as string,\n\t\tActiveIndicator as boolean,\n\t\tSortOrder as integer\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet',\n\tpartitionFileNames:['SalesTransactionUS.parquet'],\n\tpartitionBy('hash', 1),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sinkToProduce"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind sharing the data flow script behind from the data flow UI?

Comment: @AT_S, Follow up to see if you have had a chance to see the previous response. We need the following information to understand/investigate this issue further.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT: Added the dataflow script